Getting undeterministic results in simple RNN
I have been working on simple rnn. I get different results for the same data and same model but different order of columns in train data.First I run the code for train data with columns A,B and C. in second i run the code with B,C and A. this change of order should not affect the model results. but i get different accuracy(like r2 score).
Something is wrong and i tried debugging.
Things that i could find:

without minmax scaler, i get same output even if order of columns changed
2.but minmax scaler provides same values even if order of column changed. only order is changed in minmax result but values remains the same.

I have read articles and research papers and tried setting seed. but this does not solve the problem.
Everyone mentions that these algorithms are not sensitive to order of columns.
Then why i get different results for different order?
This is my code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import SimpleRNN, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")  
features = ['HOLIDAY_FLAG', 'TEMPERATURE','PROMOTION_ACTIVE', 'PRODUCT_PRICE',  'YEAR', 'MONTH', 'WEEK', 'QUARTER']
target = 'PRODUCTS_SOLD'
data = df[features + [target]]
train_size = int(len(data) * 0.80)
X = data[features]
y = data[[target]]
X_train, X_test = X[:train_size], X[train_size:]
y_train, y_test = y[:train_size], y[train_size:]
scaler_X, scaler_y = MinMaxScaler(), MinMaxScaler()
X_train, X_test = scaler_X.fit_transform(X_train), scaler_X.transform(X_test)
y_train, y_test = scaler_y.fit_transform(y_train), scaler_y.transform(y_test)
X_train, X_test = X_train.reshape(-1, 1, X_train.shape[1]), X_test.reshape(-1, 1, X_test.shape[1])
model= Sequential([
    SimpleRNN(50, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])),
    Dropout(0.2),
    SimpleRNN(50, activation='tanh'),
    Dense(1)
])
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=2, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), shuffle=False)
y_pred = scaler_y.inverse_transform(model.predict(X_test))
y_test = scaler_y.inverse_transform(y_test)
print(f"R2 Score: {r2_score(y_test, y_pred) * 100:.2f}%")


As Said i tried debugging my code but could not find the problem.
I tried with other data, thing data was te problem but i was wrong.
Change the order of train data and you will get different r2score.
i need same accuracy even if i change the order of columns.
